# Hosting reseller banahosting

Tags: linux

Buenos días , en el hostin reseller que adquirí en **banahosting** me dieron estos datos para configurar en mi dominio que lo tengo en namecheap:

```
Primary DNS: ns1.dominio.com 109.163.211.143
Secondary DNS: ns2.dominio.com 91.128.171.98
```

como puedo configurar los nameserver y apuntarlos con los ips que me están dando ahí?

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que ir a los detalles de su dominio, y luego al tab NameServers y colocas los nuevos. Tienes que esperar un rato hasta unas 24h para que se actualice las nuevas ips en internet.

Answer (score 0):

El proceso recomendado por pasos:

Primero, en **Namecheap**, necesitaremos registrar esas *IP*s como *Nameservers* de nuestro dominio (sub-dominios de tipo *NS*) para esto ve a "**Domain List**" luego clic en el boton "**Manage**" del dominio, clic en "**Advanced DNS**" y luego clic en el link "**Add New Record**" aquí agregas los datos de la siguiente manera:

```
Type: NS record
Host: ns1
Value: 109.163.211.143
TTL: Automatic
```

Esto seria para el primer registro, luego repites el proceso para el segundo *Nameserver*:

```
Type: NS record
Host: ns2
Value: 91.128.171.98
TTL: Automatic
```

Esto resultaría en dos sub-dominios: **ns1.*tudominio.tld*** y **ns2.*tudominio.tld***

Ahora solo debemos usar estos sub-dominios como *Nameservers*:

Vamos a "**Domain List**", luego clic en el boton "**Manage**", en la sección "**Domain**" bajas hasta ver la sección "**Nameservers**" ahí tendrás varias opciones, selecciona "**CustomDNS**" y agregas los *NS* que creamos antes:

DNS1 (o NS1): ns1.*tudominio.tld*

DNS2 (o NS2): ns2.*tudominio.tld*

Guardas los cambios haciendo clic en el check verde al lado de la equis, y esperas a que se propaguen los cambios. Esto puede tomar hasta 24 horas, aunque personalmente nunca me ha pasado de una hora.

Espero te sirva.

Comment: No funciona , sale error "Por favor proporciona una dirección de formato correcto"

Comment: ¿En que paso te sale ese error?